# Problems about cadlag functions.

Tags: real-analysis

$f$ is a cadlag function on $[0,1]$,i.e. right continuous and has left limits for all $x\in[0,1]$.

How to prove:

for all $\epsilon>0$

$\{x_0\in[0,1]|f \text{ has a jump on }x_0 \text{ larger than }\epsilon\}$ is a finite set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A = \{x_0\in[0,1] : f \text{ has a jump on }x_0 \text{ larger than }\epsilon\}$. If $A$ contains infinite number of points, then there exists $\{x_n\} \subset A$ such that $x_n \to x \in [0,1]$

If $x_n$ converge to $x$ from the right side, then since $f$ is cadlag we have $$f(x_n) \to f(x)$$ But at the same time $|f(x_n) - f(x_n-)| > \epsilon$, which means for any $n$ we can find $k_n$ such that $x_n - \frac{1}{k_n} > x$ and $$|f(x_n) - f(x_n - \frac{1}{k_n})| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$  But $x_n - \frac{1}{k_n}$ also convergs to $x$ from the right side, so we should have $$f(x_n -\frac{1}{k_n}) \to f(x)$$
Now we get an obvious contradiction.

Similarly we can find contradiction when $x_n$ coverges to $x$ from the left side.